# (bootstrap) How to align navigation on the same line as the header (logo)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

This is what I have so far: (using bootstrap)

```
 <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Title <small>Secondary Text</small></h1>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="register.html">Register</a></li>
                <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The page-header creates a horizontal line and I want the navigation menu above that line, aligned on the right and the title on the left. For some reason it keeps going below the horizontal line.

I tried using div container-fluid, but the title jumps up and isn't resting on the horizontal line at that point.

All help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`display: flex;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) on your `.page-header` to position the elements next to each other.

With `flex: 1;` on `h1` and `.nav` both get the same amount of space from the viewport width (50%). Of course you can adjust this value for your needs. On small viewport widths you will have to adjust the styles, e.g. with media queries.

```css
.page-header {
  display: flex;
}

h1,
.nav {
  flex: 1;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 0 !important;
}

.nav {
  text-align: right;
}

.nav.nav-pills>li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Title <small>Secondary Text</small></h1>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="register.html">Register</a></li>
      <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped. I'm trying to figure out how to increase the distance between the nav and the title, to push the nav more to the right. Is there anyway to do this? Edit: figured it out, margin-left on the .nav css. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Yes it's possible, updated my answer. You will have to override bootstraps styles with higher specificity and make your nav `<li>`s non floating and `display: inline-block`. Now you can set `text-align:right` on the parent and your nav element should align to the right.

Answer (score 3):

It's a small problem with you  tag wrapping. You have wrapped all elements under the page-header.This is your first mistake. The starting div must be page-header and then followed by container in which h1 and ul elements are present.

Second mistake is when you tried to pull ul the elements to the left.There are no elements that are pull to right. Because of this the browser thinks it as a new line instead of the same one.Therefore, you need to wrap the h1 with a div with class pull-left.

This would work according to your wish.

```
<body>
  <div class="page-header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="pull-left">
                <h1>Title <small>Secondary Text</small></h1>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="register.html">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Secondary Text within the h1 would not be my choice (SEO wise). Other than that, very nice answer!

Comment: I just answered the possible and easy way to fix the problem. h1 element is not altered by me , it is the same as given by the user.

Comment: Ah... I see! [thumbs up]

Comment: This may sound like a stupid question (as i am new to html/css/bootstrap) but i dont understand why the container goes after your first div class? Could you please explain? Thank you

Comment: page-header div is a class in bootstrap, it just tell the html that whenever a page-header class is used create a space and bottom line to that. Basically it tells that, you need to create a page-header. After that i am using a container class because the container class is the actual div class which wraps all the h1 and div elements in it, not the page-header.

Comment: @SaiPavan - Just saw this and forgot to reply. Thank you for replying and for the explanation :)